# Cannot render an image over filled rectangles

Tags: java

The healthBars (filled rectangles) are not allowing anything to render after them in this java game. However, The healthBarBorders need to appear on top, because they are essentially a frame with an alpha inside, allowing the rectangles to be seen through. Because the rectangles come from the Swing class and the other things being rendered arent, this is were the issue is coming from. Any workarounds?

```
public void render() {

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    //RENDER HERE
    backgroundImage.render(g);
    player.render(g);
    healthBars.render(g); //The rectangles (
    healthBarBorders.render(g);

    //END RENDER
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

HealthBar class

```
public class HealthBar extends JComponent {

        int healthP1;
        int healthP2;

        public void render(Graphics g) {
            paintComponent(g); //maybe this.paintComponent(g);
        }

        //Constructor
        public HealthBar(int healthP1, int healthP2) {
            this.healthP1 = healthP1;
            this.healthP2 = healthP2;
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            //Player 1 health bar
            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            Rectangle redBarP1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 300, 30);
            g2.fill(redBarP1);

            g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            Rectangle greenBarP1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, healthP1, 30);
            g2.fill(greenBarP1);

            //Player 2 health bar
            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            Rectangle redBarP2 = new Rectangle(800, 10, 300, 30);
            g2.fill(redBarP2);

            g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            Rectangle greenBarP2 = new Rectangle(800, 10, healthP2, 30);
            g2.fill(greenBarP2);

            g2.dispose(); //Double check if I need this here
        }
    }
```

BackgroundImage render method:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.drawImage(background, 0, -27, 1200, 600, null);
}
```

Player render method:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    if(attack)
        attackAnimation.render(g, x, y, 400 * Game.SCALE, 400* Game.SCALE);
    else
        g.drawImage(im.player, x, y, 400 * Game.SCALE, 400 * Game.SCALE, null);
}
```

HealthBarBorders render method:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.drawImage(healthBorder1, 10, 10, 300, 30, null);
    g2.drawImage(healthBorder2, 800, 10, 300, 30, null);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to supply the code for `healthBars` and probably all the other `render` methods as well, 'cause at the moment, it's all guess work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `public class HealthBar extends JComponent {` scares me...
2. `paintComponent(g); //maybe this.paintComponent(g);` scares me...
3. `g2.dispose(); //Double check if I need this here` no you don't and is the cause of your problem...

There is no need for `HealthBar` to extend from `JComponent`.  In fact it could be argued that you should be using a `interface` which defines a simple `render` method and each of your entities should implement it...

But the core of your problem is calling `dispose` on a `Graphics` context that you did not create